# Changing Value of an Attribute in a Model when a post takes place

Tags: python, django

I have made a blog where a user can like or unlike, so everything is working fine now but I have tried to add a Like Model to view more details related to each like that takes place by which user and when.

In the Like Model I have added a value for each model and choices are `Like` and 'Unlike'

I have tried in the views to use `get_or_create` but it cause an error `TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <built-in function id>.`

and I tried to add the value incase a like and unlike is made it returned `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'save'`

I am going to show the view with my trials commented

First here is the post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    content = RichTextUploadingField(null=True, blank=True)
    num_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='No. of Likes')
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='liked', blank=True)
```

Here is the like model:

```
LIKE_CHOICES = (
    ('Like', 'Like'),
    ('Unlike', 'Unlike')
)

class Like(models.Model):
    # To know Who liked
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.CharField(choices=LIKE_CHOICES, max_length=8)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Here is the views.py

```
def LikeView(request):
    # post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('id'))
    liked = False
    current_likes = post.num_likes
    user = request.user

    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        liked = False
        current_likes = current_likes - 1
        # Like.value=='Unlike'(..2nd Trial..)

    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        liked = True
        current_likes = current_likes + 1
        # Like.value=='Like'(..2nd Trial..)

  # Like.value.save()       (..2nd Trial..)
    post.num_likes=current_likes
    post.save()

#-----------------------1st trial--------------------
#         like, created = Like.objects.get_or_create(user=user, id=id)
#         if not created:
#             if like.value == 'Like':
#                 like.value = 'Unlike'
#             else:
#                 like.value = 'Like'
#         like.save()
# ----------------------------------------------------------

    context = {
        'total_likes': post.total_likes,
        'liked': liked,
        'post': post
    }

    if request.is_ajax:
        html = render_to_string('blog/like_section.html', context, request=request)
        return JsonResponse({'form': html})
```

My question:

When a user clicks the like button how do I create an new like with the value of 'Like'?

Comment: `id` is a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) in Python and you never assign a value to a variable `id`, hence your TypeError.

Comment: @PGHE what would be a good practice to rectify it in this case?

Comment: from where that ***`id`*** comes? its coming from nowhere, @A_K

Comment: @ArakkalAbu i was following a guide and it was `(user=user, post_id=post_id)` but it also caused an error `TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <Post: Blog No.1>.` Does this makes sense? Sorry bear with me I am trying to understand and learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `id` then you don't need to use the `user` field. So you can try this way:

```
like, created = Like.objects.get_or_create(user=user, post=post)
```

The above code will create or just fetch a Like object or record with the specified user & post. i.e the user has liked the post.

And I think you should also set default value for the `value` field in Like Model.

**Like model**

```
LIKE_CHOICES = (
    ('like', 'Like'),
    ('unlike', 'Unlike')
)

class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.CharField(choices=LIKE_CHOICES, max_length=8, default='like') #like this
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```